# QML ListView current item not changing with keystrokes or mouse

Tags: qt, qml

I have a very simple ListView.

```
ListView {
    id: logListView
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: LogEntryListModel

    delegate:
        Text {
        text: "Log Item: " + timestamp + ", " + verb
    }
    highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
    focus: true
    clip: true
}
```

It shows the model fine and highlights the first item. It does not move the highlight when I click on another item nor when I use the arrow keys.  I know how to control the highlighted item manually by adding event handlers but I see references in the docs to automatic handling of the selectedItem.  I was wondering:

Does QML provide an automatic changing of the selected item highlighting?  What do I need to add to turn it on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keyboard handling is done automatically:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    ListView {
        id: logListView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 10

        delegate: Text {
            text: "Log Item: " + modelData
        }
        highlight: Rectangle { 
            color: "lightsteelblue"; 
            radius: 5
        }
        focus: true
        clip: true
    }
}
```

If using the up and down arrow keys does not change the selected item for you, using the code above, then it's a bug.

Using a mouse to select items is not handled by default, however; only flicking/dragging of the list is. It's easy to add, though:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    ListView {
        id: logListView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 10

        delegate: Text {
            text: "Log Item: " + modelData

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: logListView.currentIndex = index
            }
        }
        highlight: Rectangle {
            color: "lightsteelblue";
            radius: 5
        }
        focus: true
        clip: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example works fine for me when I start it from scratch, even when I separate the ListView into another QML file.  I must have something intercepting the keystrokes before the get to the ListView.

Comment: This is quite old, but I was having the same issue as Nathanial. Perhaps this is new, but a quick fix for a similar situation is [forceActiveFocus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#forceActiveFocus-method). `onClicked: { logListView.currentIndex = index; logListView.forceActiveFocus(); }` worked for me